# unmerge excel cell while download from rdlc in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, rdlc

I'm trying to download rdlc report in excel format from my website. After downloading come of the columns are merging. How can avoid this merging. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to avoid "merging" of the columns in Excel is to contain the whole report inside Table with individual items in separate table cells, also you should make sure your vertical and horizontal alignments are consistent.

If it's not possible to place it entirely into Table, then carefully align all the fields on the report - this will minimize columns and rows merging.

Answer (score 0):

Please change(column width) in Design view of RDLc your issue will be solve